# My page won't scroll down once my content goes past the footer

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a school project. I am new to html. My page won't scroll down once my content goes past the footer. How do I fix this? Why won't it scroll down? I would like to keep my footer at the bottom and I tried playing around with it but can't seem to get it right.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>TRIP TO LONDON</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<style>
<!-- 
Jasmine
Web Programming 1
10/28/14

- ids can be used 1 time per html page
- classes can be used unlimited time per html page
- ids typically contain margin, width of the divs
- classes contain styles of the divs

WCAG Guidelines (Section 508) WAI > W3C
AA - Headings Navigation
AAA - large bodies of text paragraphs -->


body {
 font-family: Helvetica;
 }

 
 #main{
  width: 950px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #ececec;
  } 
  
  <!--center div-->
  
 #banner{
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-right: 45px;
  border: medium;
  }
  
.bg {
background-color:#ececec;
font-size: 88.5%;
font-family: helvetica;
}

 #content{
  width: 850px;
  margin-top: 50px;}

 #left{
  width: 450px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
  }
   
 #bottom {
  width: 450px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  }
  
 #right{
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
  }
  

 #footer{
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #4285f4;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
 }

.grid1{
 color: #000000;
 background-color: #FFFFFF; 
 font-family: sans-serif;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #888888;
 }

.grid2{
 color:#000000;
 background-color: #FFFFFF; 
 border-style: dashed;
 border-width: 5px;
 border-color: #000000;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #888888;
 }
 
 #banner1
 {
background: #4285f4;
color: white;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
right: 0;
padding: 10px;
height: 30px;
text-align: center;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
font-family: Helvetica;
font-size: 18px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body id="body" class="bg">
<div id="main"> &nbsp;
<div id="banner1">TRIP TO LONDON</div><!--close banner-->
<div id="content"> &nbsp;

  <div id="left" class="grid1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sagittis turpis ut sapien egestas euismod. Pellentesque a ultricies neque. Cras sed nisl mollis, iaculis metus vel, venenatis lectus. Cras nisi orci, convallis sit amet nibh ac, vestibulum aliquet lectus. Curabitur eget cursus lorem. Praesent hendrerit in nunc non rutrum. Suspendisse ac elit vitae odio condimentum consequat. Cras a fringilla dui, dapibus lacinia quam. Sed quis sagittis ante. Quisque non congue lacus, et scelerisque arcu. Cras cursus finibus gravida. Nulla id lacus consequat, finibus quam ac, ultricies purus. Curabitur scelerisque massa id leo malesuada, vel semper quam venenatis. Fusce viverra, erat at convallis laoreet, tellus erat bibendum nulla, id dapibus tellus orci viverra leo. Cras posuere id nibh at ornare. Praesent luctus magna et lacus malesuada, id ullamcorper enim vulputate. Donec vestibulum nisi sit amet vulputate consequat. Proin ultricies mi felis. Nunc accumsan venenatis ornare. Maecenas luctus venenatis accumsan. Vestibulum sit amet augue sit amet leo sollicitudin accumsan vel non massa. Morbi sodales lacus massa, non accumsan risus tempus ut. Proin convallis auctor tortor, eu venenatis turpis congue nec. Donec quam velit, volutpat bibendum metus blandit, porttitor condimentum diam.</div><!--close left-->

  <div id="right" class="grid1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sagittis turpis ut sapien egestas euismod. Pellentesque a ultricies neque. Cras sed nisl mollis, iaculis metus vel, venenatis lectus. Cras nisi orci, convallis sit amet nibh ac, vestibulum aliquet lectus. Curabitur eget cursus lorem. Praesent hendrerit in nunc non rutrum. Suspendisse ac elit vitae odio condimentum consequat. Cras a fringilla dui, dapibus lacinia quam. Sed quis sagittis ante. Quisque non congue lacus, et scelerisque arcu. Cras cursus finibus gravida. Nulla id lacus consequat, finibus quam ac, ultricies purus. Curabitur scelerisque massa id leo malesuada, vel semper quam venenatis. Fusce viverra, erat at convallis laoreet, tellus erat bibendum nulla, id dapibus tellus orci viverra leo. Cras posuere id nibh at ornare. Praesent luctus magna et lacus malesuada, id ullamcorper enim vulputate. Donec vestibulum nisi sit amet vulputate consequat. Proin ultricies mi felis. Nunc accumsan venenatis ornare. Maecenas luctus venenatis accumsan. Vestibulum sit amet augue sit amet leo sollicitudin accumsan vel non massa. Morbi sodales lacus massa, non accumsan risus tempus ut. Proin convallis auctor tortor, eu venenatis turpis congue nec. Donec quam velit, volutpat bibendum metus blandit, porttitor condimentum diam. 
</div><!--close right-->

<div id="bottom" class="grid1"> Donec vestibulum nisi sit amet vulputate consequat. Proin ultricies mi felis. Nunc accumsan venenatis ornare. Maecenas luctus venenatis accumsan. Vestibulum sit amet augue sit amet leo sollicitudin accumsan vel non massa. Morbi sodales lacus massa, non accumsan risus tempus ut. Proin convallis auctor tortor, eu venenatis turpis congue nec. Donec quam velit, volutpat bibendum metus blandit, porttitor condimentum diam. sit amet augue sit amet leo sollicitudin accumsan vel non massa. Morbi sodales lacus massa, elis. Nunc accumsan venenatis ornare. Maecenas luctus venenatis accumsan. Vestibulum sit amet augue sit amet leo sollicitudin accumsan vel non massa. Morbi sodales lacus massa, non accumsan risus tempus ut. Proin convallis auctor tortor, eu venenatis turpis congue nec. Donec quam velit, volutpat bibendum metus bla.

</div>
</div><!--close content-->
<div id="footer">J.O. Copyright 2014</div><!--close footer-->
</div><!--close main-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add overflow:y into your body [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ovyrwsne/)

Comment: your css is probably off, set a height property for your element that is supposed to go down below the footer, that way the footer is pushed down further

Comment: "ids typically contain margin, width of the divs"? This is totally wrong :)

Comment: @BojanPetkovski He is talking about his ID selectors, and that he typically puts div margin and width properties in them. He's not talking about inherent properties of IDs.

Comment: you may also find use to [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)

Comment: @TylerH If it is about his ids than I guess it is ok :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your content is going off too far below and you can't scroll it means the element containing the content isn't big enough. Try to set the element that has all the content with a larger height value (I'm guessing the body element in your case)

so in your css if:
 `height:800px`

set it to 
`height:1200px`

or enough to hold all the content

Comment: Thank you. I just put height to the main and it worked.

Comment: This will not work if you add more content. Will you change the height every time you add more content??? If you have less content it will have a blank space :)

Comment: well he can figure out how much content there is in total, and decide his height based on that

Comment: @AbdulAhmad If this is used on a dynamic site will you calculate the height manually on every page??? Make it once properly and it will work everywhere as it is supposed to do :)

Comment: no, but from the looks of this site its not dynamic, I agree with you if it was supposed to be dynamic, but for a school project that has 1 focus I think he knows exactly what he needs to put

Answer (score 2):

Your content is scrolled to the bottom of your page as it is supposed to do. You can't see it because you have your footer on top of your content with a fixed position. The simple solution is to put height on your footer and add the same height as padding to the content. Or just add some padding-bottom to #content like this. And add overflow: hidden to #content so it has height. If the parent is filled with floated children element it doesn't have height. So either add overflow: hidden; or use a clearfix :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>TRIP TO LONDON</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<style>
<!-- 
Jasmine
Web Programming 1
10/28/14

- ids can be used 1 time per html page
- classes can be used unlimited time per html page
- ids typically contain margin, width of the divs
- classes contain styles of the divs

WCAG Guidelines (Section 508) WAI > W3C
AA - Headings Navigation
AAA - large bodies of text paragraphs -->


body {
 font-family: Helvetica;
 }

 
 #main{
  width: 950px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #ececec;
  } 
  
  <!--center div-->
  
 #banner{
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-right: 45px;
  border: medium;
  }
  
.bg {
background-color:#ececec;
font-size: 88.5%;
font-family: helvetica;
}

 #content{
  width: 850px;
  margin-top: 50px; 
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
  

 #left{
  width: 450px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
  }
   
 #bottom {
  width: 450px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  }
  
 #right{
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
  }
  

 #footer{
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #4285f4;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
 }

.grid1{
 color: #000000;
 background-color: #FFFFFF; 
 font-family: sans-serif;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #888888;
 }

.grid2{
 color:#000000;
 background-color: #FFFFFF; 
 border-style: dashed;
 border-width: 5px;
 border-color: #000000;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #888888;
 }
 
 #banner1
 {
background: #4285f4;
color: white;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
right: 0;
padding: 10px;
height: 30px;
text-align: center;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
font-family: Helvetica;
font-size: 18px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body id="body" class="bg">
<div id="main"> &nbsp;
<div id="banner1">TRIP TO LONDON</div><!--close banner-->
<div id="content"> &nbsp;

  <div id="left" class="grid1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sagittis turpis ut sapien egestas euismod. Pellentesque a ultricies neque. Cras sed nisl mollis, iaculis metus vel, venenatis lectus. Cras nisi orci, convallis sit amet nibh ac, vestibulum aliquet lectus. Curabitur eget cursus lorem. Praesent hendrerit in nunc non rutrum. Suspendisse ac elit vitae odio condimentum consequat. Cras a fringilla dui, dapibus lacinia quam. Sed quis sagittis ante. Quisque non congue lacus, et scelerisque arcu. Cras cursus finibus gravida. Nulla id lacus consequat, finibus quam ac, ultricies purus. Curabitur scelerisque massa id leo malesuada, vel semper quam venenatis. Fusce viverra, erat at convallis laoreet, tellus erat bibendum nulla, id dapibus tellus orci viverra leo. Cras posuere id nibh at ornare. Praesent luctus magna et lacus malesuada, id ullamcorper enim vulputate. Donec vestibulum nisi sit amet vulputate consequat. Proin ultricies mi felis. Nunc accumsan venenatis ornare. Maecenas luctus venenatis accumsan. Vestibulum sit amet augue sit amet leo sollicitudin accumsan vel non massa. Morbi sodales lacus massa, non accumsan risus tempus ut. Proin convallis auctor tortor, eu venenatis turpis congue nec. Donec quam velit, volutpat bibendum metus blandit, porttitor condimentum diam.</div><!--close left-->

  <div id="right" class="grid1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sagittis turpis ut sapien egestas euismod. Pellentesque a ultricies neque. Cras sed nisl mollis, iaculis metus vel, venenatis lectus. Cras nisi orci, convallis sit amet nibh ac, vestibulum aliquet lectus. Curabitur eget cursus lorem. Praesent hendrerit in nunc non rutrum. Suspendisse ac elit vitae odio condimentum consequat. Cras a fringilla dui, dapibus lacinia quam. Sed quis sagittis ante. Quisque non congue lacus, et scelerisque arcu. Cras cursus finibus gravida. Nulla id lacus consequat, finibus quam ac, ultricies purus. Curabitur scelerisque massa id leo malesuada, vel semper quam venenatis. Fusce viverra, erat at convallis laoreet, tellus erat bibendum nulla, id dapibus tellus orci viverra leo. Cras posuere id nibh at ornare. Praesent luctus magna et lacus malesuada, id ullamcorper enim vulputate. Donec vestibulum nisi sit amet vulputate consequat. Proin ultricies mi felis. Nunc accumsan venenatis ornare. Maecenas luctus venenatis accumsan. Vestibulum sit amet augue sit amet leo sollicitudin accumsan vel non massa. Morbi sodales lacus massa, non accumsan risus tempus ut. Proin convallis auctor tortor, eu venenatis turpis congue nec. Donec quam velit, volutpat bibendum metus blandit, porttitor condimentum diam. 
</div><!--close right-->

<div id="bottom" class="grid1"> Donec vestibulum nisi sit amet vulputate consequat. Proin ultricies mi felis. Nunc accumsan venenatis ornare. Maecenas luctus venenatis accumsan. Vestibulum sit amet augue sit amet leo sollicitudin accumsan vel non massa. Morbi sodales lacus massa, non accumsan risus tempus ut. Proin convallis auctor tortor, eu venenatis turpis congue nec. Donec quam velit, volutpat bibendum metus blandit, porttitor condimentum diam. sit amet augue sit amet leo sollicitudin accumsan vel non massa. Morbi sodales lacus massa, elis. Nunc accumsan venenatis ornare. Maecenas luctus venenatis accumsan. Vestibulum sit amet augue sit amet leo sollicitudin accumsan vel non massa. Morbi sodales lacus massa, non accumsan risus tempus ut. Proin convallis auctor tortor, eu venenatis turpis congue nec. Donec quam velit, volutpat bibendum metus bla.

</div>
</div><!--close content-->
<div id="footer">J.O. Copyright 2014</div><!--close footer-->
</div><!--close main-->
</body>
</html>
```